# does chrome compatible with openxr on android?

Tags: google-chrome, openxr

I have installed correct openxr runtime on 3D device which runs android10 system, after recompiled wolvic browser with coresponding openxr runtime loader, wolvic works perfectly, it does rendered 3D scenes into space, it means the openxr runtime is no problem.

But with chrome browser, it can not render 3D scene and have crashed when ever after a popup to ask authourise 3D device permision, authough i have set chrome://flags options include 'openxr enbled' and webxr runtime using 'openxr'.

following is a part of crash reports:

```
-----MultipartBoundary-JNBm6wYdUeXtrTFLMhbtmALWoI3pTqwy---
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="logcat"; filename="logcat"
Content-Type: text/plain

10-07 15:59:58.686  6365  6399 I chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(55)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
10-07 15:59:58.686  6365  6399 I cr_LibraryLoader: Successfully loaded native library
10-07 15:59:58.687  6365  6365 W HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
10-07 15:59:58.687  6365  6399 I cr_CachingUmaRecorder: Flushed 10 samples from 10 histograms, 0 samples were dropped.
10-07 15:59:58.687  6365  6365 W HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
10-07 15:59:58.691  6365  6365 I cr_CompositorSurfaceMgr: Transitioning to surface with format: -1
10-07 15:59:58.731  6365  6395 D cr_tabmodel: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] Starting to fetch tab list for tab_state0
10-07 15:59:58.732  6365  6395 D cr_tabmodel: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] Finished fetching tab list.
10-07 15:59:58.734  6365  6397 D cr_tabmodel: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] Starting to fetch tab list for tab_state1
10-07 15:59:58.734  6365  6397 D cr_tabmodel: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] State file does not exist.
10-07 15:59:58.745  6365  6365 D cr_TabFeatureUtilities: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED = 2048

10-07 15:59:58.802  6365  6365 D cr_BrowserStartup: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=false
10-07 15:59:58.827  6365  6365 W chromium: [WARNING:trace_startup_config.cc(240)] The trace config file does not exist.
10-07 15:59:58.835  6405  6405 I AppZygoteInit: Beginning application preload for org.chromium.chrome.dev
10-07 15:59:58.842  6405  6405 I cr_ZygotePreload: Loaded Zygote. version=118.0.5939.0 minSdkVersion=1 isBundle=false
10-07 15:59:58.843  6405  6405 W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.chromium.chrome.dev-QvAoJ9cSRmR8KlfRgXxbDA==/lib/arm64/HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED" unused DT entry: unknown processor-specific (type 0x70000001 arg 0x0) (ignoring)
10-07 15:59:58.844  6365  6365 W chromium: [WARNING:field_trial_util.cc(104)] Field trial config study skipped: RawDrawAndDrDc.DrDc_vulkan (some of its features are already overridden)
10-07 15:59:58.848  6405  6405 I AppZygoteInit: Application preload done
10-07 15:59:58.853  6365  6365 W chromium: [WARNING:file_util_posix.cc(665)] OS_ANDROID: Home directory lookup not yet implemented.
10-07 15:59:58.855  6405  6405 D Zygote  : Forked child process 6418
10-07 15:59:58.890  6365  6427 D NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
10-07 15:59:58.905  6365  6365 I chromium: [INFO:policy_logger.cc(142)] :components/enterprise/browser/controller/chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(273) Deferring CBCM Controller Initialization until it is unblocked.
10-07 15:59:58.907  6365  6404 D cr_ChildConnAllocator: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] Allocator allocated and bound a connection, name: org.chromium.content.app.PrivilegedProcessService, slot: 0
10-07 15:59:58.907  6365  6404 W HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED: Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/Context;->bindServiceAsUser(Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/content/ServiceConnection;ILandroid/os/Handler;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
10-07 15:59:58.926  6453  6453 I ileged_process: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-07 15:59:58.939  6453  6453 E ileged_process: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
10-07 15:59:58.969  6453  6453 I Perf    : Connecting to perf service.
10-07 15:59:58.981  6453  6453 I cr_SplitCompatApp: Launched version=118.0.5939.0 minSdkVersion=1 isBundle=false processName=org.chromium.chrome.dev:privileged_process0 isIsolated=false
10-07 15:59:58.985  6453  6453 I cr_ChildProcessService: Creating new ChildProcessService pid=6453
10-07 15:59:58.993  6365  6404 D cr_ChildProcLauncher: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] on connect callback, pid=6453
10-07 15:59:58.993  6365  6365 E chromium: [ERROR:shell_integration_android.cc(44)] Not implemented reached in DefaultWebClientSetPermission shell_integration::internal::GetPlatformSpecificDefaultWebClientSetPermission(WebClientSetMethod)
10-07 15:59:58.995  6453  6474 W linker  : Warning: "/data/app/org.chromium.chrome.dev-QvAoJ9cSRmR8KlfRgXxbDA==/lib/arm64/HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED" unused DT entry: unknown processor-specific (type 0x70000001 arg 0x0) (ignoring)

10-07 15:59:59.011  6453  6474 W chromium: [WARNING:trace_startup_config.cc(240)] The trace config file does not exist.

10-07 15:59:59.037  6365  6365 D cr_SmsProviderGms: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] Creating SmsProviderGms
10-07 15:59:59.037  6365  6365 W GooglePlayServicesUtil: org.chromium.chrome.dev requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
10-07 15:59:59.038  6365  6365 I cr_SmsProviderGms: construction successfull null, org.chromium.content.browser.sms.SmsUserConsentReceiver@34afdda
10-07 15:59:59.046  6453  6474 D vulkan  : searching for layers in '/data/app/org.chromium.chrome.dev-QvAoJ9cSRmR8KlfRgXxbDA==/lib/arm64'
10-07 15:59:59.046  6453  6474 D vulkan  : searching for layers in '/data/app/org.chromium.chrome.dev-QvAoJ9cSRmR8KlfRgXxbDA==/HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED!/lib/arm64-v8a'

10-07 15:59:59.061  6365  6426 E chromium: [ERROR:shell_integration_android.cc(27)] Not implemented reached in DefaultWebClientState shell_integration::GetDefaultBrowser()
10-07 15:59:59.065  6365  6365 W GooglePlayServicesUtil: org.chromium.chrome.dev requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
10-07 15:59:59.066  6365  6365 V cr_ExternalAuthUtils: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] Unable to use Google Play Services: SERVICE_INVALID

10-07 15:59:59.156  6365  6365 E VpsExtension: Failed to get binder for service "HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED"
10-07 15:59:59.156  6365  6365 E VpsExtension: Failed to get binder for service "HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED"
10-07 15:59:59.157  6365  6365 I cr_CompositorSurfaceMgr: surfaceCreated format: 0
10-07 15:59:59.166  6365  6365 I cr_ChromeTabbedActivity: #initializeState
10-07 15:59:59.190  6365  6426 D cr_ULP  : [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] ULP not available

10-07 15:59:59.252  6365  6427 D cr_AndroidFontLookup: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] Failed to get font with: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: No package found for authority: com.google.android.gms.fonts
10-07 15:59:59.254  6365  6427 I chatty  : uid=10126(org.chromium.chrome.dev) ThreadPoolForeg identical 2 lines
10-07 15:59:59.254  6365  6427 D cr_AndroidFontLookup: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] Failed to get font with: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: No package found for authority: com.google.android.gms.fonts
10-07 15:59:59.368  6365  6365 I cr_OfflineIndicator: onConnectionTypeChanged 2
10-07 15:59:59.369  6365  6365 I cr_OfflineIndicator: Reported by system: [ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps SignalStrength: -16]
10-07 15:59:59.369  6365  6365 I cr_OfflineIndicator: setConnectionState connectionState=4
10-07 15:59:59.369  6365  6365 W Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
10-07 15:59:59.373  6365  6365 I cr_OfflineDetector: Received connection change state message. mConnectivityDetectorInitialized: true, mTimeWhenLastForegrounded: 407412, getElapsedTime: 407416, mTimeWhenLastOfflineNotificationReceived: 0, mTimeWhenLastOnline: 407416, mTimeWhenAirplaneModeToggledOff: 0 mApplicationState: 1, mIsOfflineLastReportedByConnectivityDetector: false, mInAirplaneMode: false mIsEffectivelyOffline: false
10-07 15:59:59.373  6365  6365 I cr_OfflineDetector: onConnectionStateChanged(): previousLastReportedStateByOfflineDetector: false
10-07 15:59:59.373  6365  6365 I cr_OfflineDetector: Running updateState mConnectivityDetectorInitialized: true, mTimeWhenLastForegrounded: 407412, getElapsedTime: 407416, mTimeWhenLastOfflineNotificationReceived: 0, mTimeWhenLastOnline: 407416, mTimeWhenAirplaneModeToggledOff: 0 mApplicationState: 1, mIsOfflineLastReportedByConnectivityDetector: false, mInAirplaneMode: false mIsEffectivelyOffline: false
10-07 15:59:59.373  6365  6365 I cr_OfflineDetector: updateState(): timeSinceLastForeground: 4, timeSinceOfflineNotificationReceived: 407416, timeSinceLastOnline: 0, timeNeededForForeground: 1996, timeNeededForOffline: -405416 timeSinceAirplaneModeToggledOff: 407416 timeNeededAfterConnectionChangeFromOnlineToOffline: 10000 timeNeededAfterConnectionChangeFromAirplaneToOffline: 0
10-07 15:59:59.373  6365  6365 I cr_OfflineDetector: Running mUpdateOfflineStatusIndicatorDelayedRunnable start. mConnectivityDetectorInitialized: true, mTimeWhenLastForegrounded: 407412, getElapsedTime: 407417, mTimeWhenLastOfflineNotificationReceived: 0, mTimeWhenLastOnline: 407416, mTimeWhenAirplaneModeToggledOff: 0 mApplicationState: 1, mIsOfflineLastReportedByConnectivityDetector: false, mInAirplaneMode: false mIsEffectivelyOffline: false
10-07 15:59:59.373  6365  6365 I cr_OfflineDetector: Running mUpdateOfflineStatusIndicatorDelayedRunnable end. mConnectivityDetectorInitialized: true, mTimeWhenLastForegrounded: 407412, getElapsedTime: 407417, mTimeWhenLastOfflineNotificationReceived: 0, mTimeWhenLastOnline: 407416, mTimeWhenAirplaneModeToggledOff: 0 mApplicationState: 1, mIsOfflineLastReportedByConnectivityDetector: false, mInAirplaneMode: false mIsEffectivelyOffline: false
10-07 15:59:59.373  6365  6365 I cr_OfflineIndicator: processConnectivityCheckResult mConnectionState=4 mConnectivityCheckingStage=1
10-07 15:59:59.389  6365  6365 E ResourcesCompat: Failed to find font-family tag
10-07 15:59:59.391  6365  6365 D cr_TabFeatureUtilities: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED = 2048
10-07 15:59:59.404  6365  6365 V cr_ContextualSearch: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] State transition 0 => 1
10-07 15:59:59.411  6365  6365 W GooglePlayServicesUtil: org.chromium.chrome.dev requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
10-07 15:59:59.439  6365  6365 I cr_JNIUtils: Init JNI Classloader for vr. isInstalled=false
10-07 15:59:59.466  6365  6365 I cr_InactivityTracker: Last background time read from the SharedPreference is:1696665582277.
10-07 15:59:59.511  6365  6365 E ResourcesCompat: Failed to find font-family tag
10-07 15:59:59.518  6365  6365 I cr_InactivityTracker: Last visible time read from the SharedPreference is:1696665565905.
10-07 15:59:59.531  6365  6365 W HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
10-07 15:59:59.531  6365  6365 W HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
10-07 15:59:59.531  6365  6365 W HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
10-07 15:59:59.531  6365  6365 W HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
10-07 15:59:59.551  6365  6365 W InputMethodManager: Ignoring onBind: cur seq=42, given seq=41
10-07 15:59:59.552  6365  6365 I Choreographer: Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-07 15:59:59.564  6365  6365 E VpsExtension: Failed to get binder for service "HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED"
10-07 15:59:59.565  6365  6365 I cr_CompositorSurfaceMgr: surfaceCreated format: 0
10-07 15:59:59.570  6365  6403 I OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=737ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=406876314609, Vsync=407584647846, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=407595700050, AnimationStart=407595733071, PerformTraversalsStart=407596678800, DrawStart=407609782915, SyncQueued=407612298123, SyncStart=407612460675, IssueDrawCommandsStart=407612624738, SwapBuffers=407613625206, FrameCompleted=407614025415, DequeueBufferDuration=102000, QueueBufferDuration=281000, 
10-07 15:59:59.582  6365  6365 D cr_tabmodel: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] Loaded tab lists; counts: 5,0
10-07 15:59:59.589  6365  6365 V OpenXR-Loader: Verbose [GENERAL | xrInitializeLoaderKHR | OpenXR-Loader] : Entering loader trampoline
10-07 15:59:59.589  6365  6365 V OpenXR-Loader: Verbose [GENERAL | xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties | OpenXR-Loader] : Entering loader trampoline
10-07 15:59:59.590  6365  6365 I openxr_loader: getActiveRuntimeCursor: Querying URI: HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED

10-07 15:59:59.593  6365  6365 I OpenXR-Loader: Got runtime: package: HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED.openxr_runtime.in_process, so filename: libopenxr_monado.so, native lib dir: /data/app/HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED.openxr_runtime.in_process-omueXY617tRFo_PnXw48aA==/lib/arm64, has functions: no
10-07 15:59:59.595  6365  6365 I OpenXR-Loader: Info [GENERAL | xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties | OpenXR-Loader] : RuntimeInterface::LoadRuntime forwarding xrInitializeLoaderKHR call to runtime after calling xrNegotiateLoaderRuntimeInterface.
10-07 15:59:59.595  6365  6365 I OpenXR-Loader: Info [GENERAL | xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties | OpenXR-Loader] : RuntimeInterface::LoadRuntime succeeded loading runtime defined in manifest file  using interface version 1 and OpenXR API version 1.0
10-07 15:59:59.595  6365  6365 V OpenXR-Loader: Verbose [GENERAL | xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties | OpenXR-Loader] : Completed loader trampoline
10-07 15:59:59.595  6365  6365 V OpenXR-Loader: Verbose [GENERAL | xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties | OpenXR-Loader] : Entering loader trampoline
10-07 15:59:59.595  6365  6365 V OpenXR-Loader: Verbose [GENERAL | xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties | OpenXR-Loader] : Completed loader trampoline
10-07 15:59:59.612  6365  6365 I cr_CompositorSurfaceMgr: SurfaceState : detach from parent : 0
10-07 15:59:59.613  6365  6365 E cr_CompositorSurfaceMgr: surfaceDestroyed format : 0
10-07 15:59:59.623  6365  6365 V cr_A11yState: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] Enabled accessibility services list updated.
10-07 15:59:59.624  6365  6365 V cr_A11yState: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] Informing listeners of changes.
10-07 15:59:59.624  6365  6365 V cr_A11yState: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] New AccessibilityState: State{isScreenReaderEnabled=false, isTouchExplorationEnabled=false, isPerformGesturesEnabled=false, isAnyAccessibilityServiceEnabled=false, isAccessibilityToolPresent=false, isSpokenFeedbackServicePresent=false, isTextShowPasswordEnabled=true, isOnlyPasswordManagersEnabled=false}
10-07 15:59:59.637  6365  6365 W HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
10-07 15:59:59.858  6365  6365 D cr_OfflinePageTO: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] building snackbar controller
10-07 15:59:59.874  6365  6365 D cr_UmaSessionStats: [HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED] registerSyntheticFieldTrial(IsDynamicColorAvailable, Disabled, 0)
10-07 15:59:59.880  6365  6365 I cr_StartSurface: Recorded HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED = false
10-07 15:59:59.885  6365  6404 I cr_BindingManager: Visible binding enabled: maxSize=-1
10-07 15:59:59.886  6365  6427 E chromium: [ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir /data/user/0/org.chromium.chrome.dev/cache/Crashpad/attachments/6c347121-b3cd-43c9-bcdd-f234e5297c59: No such file or directory (2)
10-07 15:59:59.900  6365  6429 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.partnerbookmarks
10-07 15:59:59.902  6365  6365 E chromium: [ERROR:notification_schedule_service_impl.cc(69)] Not implemented reached in void notifications::NotificationScheduleServiceImpl::OnInitialized(bool)
10-07 15:59:59.902  6365  6365 E chromium: [ERROR:webui_client.cc(25)] Not implemented reached in virtual void notifications::WebUIClient::OnSchedulerInitialized(bool, std::set<std::string>)
10-07 15:59:59.918  6365  6427 I cr_ProcessInitHandler: Attempting to upload 10 accumulated crash dumps.
10-07 15:59:59.919  6365  6427 I cr_MinidumpJobService: Scheduling upload of all pending minidumps.
10-07 15:59:59.920  6365  6426 I cr_LogcatCrashExtractor: Trying to extract logcat for minidump 6c347121-b3cd-43c9-bcdd-f234e5297c59.dmp3800.
-----MultipartBoundary-JNBm6wYdUeXtrTFLMhbtmALWoI3pTqwy---

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="exception_info"

java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy1.onAttachedToWindow(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onAttachedToWindow(DecorView.java:1713)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20109)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3430)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2053)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1746)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7775)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1041)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:864)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:798)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1026)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at org.chromium.base.ApplicationStatus$WindowCallbackProxy.invoke(ApplicationStatus.java:279)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED(HTTP://WEBADDRESS.ELIDED)' on a null object reference
    at com.yyss.arcore.client.ArcoreClient.destory(ArcoreClient.java:195)
    at org.chromium.base.natives.GEN_JNI.org_chromium_components_webxr_XrSessionCoordinator_onXrHostActivityReady(Native Method)
    at org.chromium.components.webxr.XrSessionCoordinatorJni.onXrHostActivityReady(XrSessionCoordinatorJni.java:59)
    at org.chromium.components.webxr.XrSessionCoordinator.handleXrHostActivityReady(XrSessionCoordinator.java:259)
    at org.chromium.components.webxr.XrSessionCoordinator.onXrHostActivityReady(XrSessionCoordinator.java:251)
    at org.chromium.components.webxr.XrHostActivity.onAttachedToWindow(XrHostActivity.java:53)
    ... 21 more
```

Anybody willing to help me with the answer?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's hard to reproduce this problem by others, because it needs the specific android device and  coresponding openxr runtime. But if you exactly have a likewise envirenment, please open your chrome browse, then visit this url : https://immersive-web.github.io/webxr-samples/immersive-vr-session.html and push the 'enter vr' button  to see whether chrome crash.